# Writing to ZipOutputStream by multiple thread

Tags: java, download, java-io, zipoutputstream

Problem: I need to download lot of files(size of file can be upto 2GB) and send those as zip to the client requesting for resource.
I was looking to parallelize that operation. Currently the library I've to use takes `OutputStream` (in my case it's `ZipOutputStream`) as input and write content of downloaded files to that output stream using ApacheCommons `IOUtils`.

Problem with this approach is everything happens sequentially. I've to download one file and then write to OutputStream, create a new zipEntry, close that entry and then go next one. 
I wanted to do the download operation in parallel and if possible I need write to `ZipOutputStream` in parallel as well.

Anyone has faced this thing before?

I was planning to change signature of that library to return `InputStream` of the downloaded resource so that I can get those content in parallel and then creating new ZipEntry for each of those stream in sequence. This way I would at least be able to download the file in parallel. 
The way I'm creating ZipOutStream is as follows:

```
ZipOutputStream zo = new ZipOutputStream(httpservletResponse.getOutputStream);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Because you don't know if the underlying format can support concurrent writes, OutputStream (and ZipOutputStream) requires you to write sequentially.

Comment: Is there any other way to make that in parallel, may be not using ZipOutputStream and using other stream which can do that in parallel?

Comment: Use a consumer-producer pattern: the consumer gets downloaded files from a blocking queue and writes them to the output stream, while the consumers, in other threads, download the files and put them in the queue.

Comment: Would [that](http://www.pixeldonor.com/2013/oct/12/concurrent-zip-compression-java-nio/) help?

Comment: Why? The network isn't parallel, and the operation is output-bound. There is no advantage to this complication.

Comment: looks like there isn't a way to write in parallel, you can save some time by preparing files to be sent in parallel, get a lock and send data to avoid concurrency exception.

Comment: @user207421 In a modern datacenter, the time to send the file (network) is way faster that the time to compress it (cpu) by a factor of x10 or more. There would be tremendous advantages to adding more cpu threads.